# What type of database should I use?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, redis, object-oriented-database

I plan to develop a web application for which I need to decide the "type" of my database system. I plan to develop the web app in Django/Python.

My application would contain just one table with 'n' increasingly growing (order of millions) records and 'k' columns (1-100). Unfortunately, I have no control over the number of 'k' viz. the size of 'k' may increase/decrease over time (between 1-100 though). I wouldn't like to have a trade off on performance.

What type of database should I use ? My initial reactions are as follows :

- MySQL : I would like to avoid this option
- Redis : Nice option but the (key,value) store doesn't fit my bill
- XML databases : Looks good for the task but does it give the desired performance?
- Object Oriented Relational DB : I am not sure on this

**Edit**
Specific Requirement :

To perform a lookup on the k-columns and retrieving a subset of 'n' records. I plan to provide a REST api similar to Twitter or Facebook.

For example, http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=Ashton . If this was what I am planning to implement the screen_name would be one of the columns. Similarly, there could be other parameters based on other columns like user_id, number of friends etc.

Comment: You database decision should focus on the queries you want to make from it, not the data you want to store in to it. Writing out N records of K fields constantly appending to a text file meets the state requirements, but that no doubt is not what you're asking. So you should rephrase the question and talk more about the other operations you want to perform.

Comment: @WillHartung I just added an edit based on your feedback. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be coming into this decision with too many preconceptions.  Why do you want to avoid MySQL?  Is it because you're avoiding rigid schema?

Redis doesn't sound like a fit because of data volume, but I don't think it has anything to do with it being a key/value store.

Your data needs sound like a pretty textboook case for [MongoBD](http://www.mongodb.org/).  Have you looked at it?

Comment: Yes, I would like to avoid MySQL due to the rigid schema. Redis doesn't fit as it can have just one key for a tuple. For example, (1,2,3,4) would represented as {1:2,3,4} in Redis. Hence, I would be able to query just on '1'. I require flexible querying on all of the values in a record. In the above e xample, 1/2/3/4. I will have a look at MongoDB.

Comment: The reason I made the point about redis is because I knew it was based on a misconception.  redis is a _lot_ more than a simple key/value store.  I haven't run into a problem yet I couldn't model in it.  It's using the same primitives to store your data as a more complex product , it just doesn't hide the complexity.  But yeah, I think you'll find mongodb is probably the best fit for you.  Completely flexibly schema, ad-hoc queries, impressive speed.  It's a schema-less store you can (mostly) query like a relational database

Comment: Going by the commands on Redis I would have to highly replicate my data. Anyways, I will look into MongoDB. However, if you think I can model my data in Redis I would love to have a look at it.

Comment: Redis isn't a good fit because it's in-memory, and it sounds like your data set will grow arbitrarily.  Also, you'd end up building a bunch of stuff that's already built into mongo.  I just wanted to make the point that there are some great options (better than we've ever had) for storage right now, and you owe it to yourself not to pigeonhole any of them.  Also, redis doesn't really duplicate data, it writes indexes.  Any other product (including mongo and mysql) that allows fast querying will do so using indexes, they've just hidden that from you.